# Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable. (Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, discord, fedora

System: Fedora 36
On my way to create a discord bot, I installed `pip` and then ran the command:

```
pip install discord
```

There was some progress bar stuff in the terminal and soon the discord was installed.
But, wait a minute, I still see that I could not use discord library in VS Code. I ran the command again in the terminal. The output was:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: discord in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py>=1.7.3 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from discord) (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.7.4.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5.0,>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in /home/Satyam/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.3)
```

After going through the article https://itsmycode.com/solved-defaulting-to-user-installation-because-normal-site-packages-is-not-writeable/ I found that this was probably due to two versions of python installed on my machine. Solutions were listed in the article as well. I tried but the first one didn't work for me. For the second solution, I didn't prefer to do it each time I started a new project.

So, is there a way to manage the two clashing versions of python?

Comment: That article is wrong, it's nothing to do with multiple versions.  You don't have permission to update /usr/lib/... so the package is installed in your home  directory.  This isn't a problem.  Writing to /usr/lib (for example by using sudo) risks breaking the system Python installation.  Either accept the --user install or use a virtualenv if you need different package versions to those already installed.